# How to build webOS app with vue 3 and vite

Tags: vue.js, webos

i'm new to webOS developping.

I've already installed the environment for it; i've noticed that there is no information about how to build a webOS app with vue. LG TV doc only tell about enact but it's React based framework. Is their a way to build it with Vue?

Comment: I believe you can build any SPA application, even vanilla JS one. You just need to transpile to the correct ECMA version of the webOS that you're targetting - e.g. LG TV 2017 do not support most of ES6 syntax.